# How to compile a class type dynamically only once?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I am deploying a client app to a mobile laptop that is configured to use one of two network servers. The network servers are identical but with different IP addresses as each is in a different office.

When the client app is first started, it needs to determine only once which office it is in and therefore which dataservice to connect to. So, using the client machine's ip address, I wish to do 
something like this:

```
 internal TYPE??? dataservice = new ResolveDataService();

  NovaDataServiceClient ResolveDataService()
  {
     if (localip == xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
      {
           retrun new DataService.NovaDataServiceClient();
      }
      else
      {
          return new LibraryWebService.NovaDataServiceClient();
      }
  }
```

Furthermore, since it only has to be done once, a static constructor would be preferred. But the real problem is that the namespace "DataService" and "LibraryWebService" were given to the Add Service Reference of the client project so in the above code

```
    internal TYPE??? dataservice
```

The Type is not known until ResolveDataService is called.

How is this done correctly?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these two services are exactly the same and just differ by IP address the right thing to do is to only have one service reference and set the endpoint when you create the service.  The easiest way in your case would probably be to add a second endpoint configuration with a different `name` attribute to the app.config and supply that in the [client's constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574925(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AlanWayne - the client has a constructor that takes a string with the endpoint configuration name.